# Can you `flutter run` on a train?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to launch a Flutter (Chrome) web app on a public WiFi (train, plane, library, coffee shop, etc).

Can you `flutter run` on a public WiFi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of

```
Flutter 3.7.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 90c64ed42b (6 days ago) • 2023-03-21 11:27:08 -0500
Engine • revision 9aa7816315
Tools • Dart 2.19.5 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

this ceased to be an issue. I can `flutter run` on a public WiFi.

###### Update

Now at

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10,
on macOS 11.7.4 20G1120 darwin-x64, locale en-CA)
```

it's again a problem, with the error

```
SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'localhost'
(OS Error: nodename nor servname provided,
or not known, errno = 8)
```

hence the question is once again open.

##### See also...

###### Use your IP

The [following](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53338) may work for you

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-port=8080 --web-hostname=101.112.123.1349
```

where the four numbers are your IP.

##### Other pointers

- [Finished with error: Failed to establish connection with the application instance in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59874808/700648)
- [How to connect device over Wifi in VScode on Mac to debug Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72497619/700648)
- [How to install and run flutter without network connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72344074/700648)
- [Problem run Flutter Web app in our company network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68049390/700648)

Answer (score 0):

try to open with the IP address of the wifi on laptop

ex: http://123.456.78.90:(port number given by Flutter)

or use ngrok and access like above

Comment: Strange.. but I cannot quite tell whether the answer you give is a serious one. Could you elaborate?

Comment: or I misunderstood the question probably. I thought you were asking about the way to access localhost remotely
if it is not, adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in AndroidManifext.xml can be a solution too

Answer (score -1):

Try to use your IP's machine, if you don't know, you can try opening a cmd terminal in windows and type `ipconfig` and get your local IP. Or terminal in linux/mac type `ifconfig` and find your local IP

Comment: Yes, this seems to work for some people, but not for me. See the updated answer.